# jar файл открывается игрой minecraft. в файле class закодированы слова. потом в игре они раскодируются. как узнать кодировку или отключить кодирование

Tags: java, разработка-игр, jar

jar файл открывается игрой minecraft. в файле class закодированы слова. потом в игре они раскодируются. как узнать кодировку или отключить кодирование
пример:
слово "abcd" раскодируется как "ik~", a "ik~" раскодируется как тоже "ik~"

```
// Decompiled by DJ v3.12.12.96 Copyright 2011 Atanas Neshkov  Date: 21.08.2019 17:02:09
// Home Page: http://members.fortunecity.com/neshkov/dj.html  http://www.neshkov.com/dj.html - Check often for new version!
// Decompiler options: packimports(3) 
// Source File Name:   ac.java

package net;

import net.minecraft.client.kb;
import net.minecraft.client.n3;
import net.minecraft.client.r0;
import net.minecraft.client.u0;
import net.minecraft.ff;

// Referenced classes of package net:
//            hb, ye, d, g, 
//            ec, o

public class ac extends hb
implements ye
{

public ac()
{
    super(z[0], 37);
    c(z[2]);
    b(z[1]);
    a(d.MOVEMENT);
}

protected void l()
{
    g.a(this);
}

protected void m()
{
    g.b(this);
}

public void a(o o1)
{
    if(i.R.Gc.d())
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_120;
label0:
    {
        if(i.R.Fc.d())
            break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_120;
        break label0;
    }
    throw ;
label1:
    {
        if(!i.y.U())
            break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_81;
        break label1;
    }
    throw ;
    i.y.q += 0.039999999105930328D;
    if(ec.p == 0)
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_120;
    break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_81;
    throw ;
    try
    {
        if(i.y.O())
            i.y.q += 0.039999999105930328D;
        break MISSING_BLOCK_LABEL_120;
    }
    catch(ff _ex) { }
    throw ;
}

public void b(o o1)
{
}

private static final String z[];

static 
{
    String as[] = new String[3];
    as;
    as;
    0;
    "Lf\006jBag";
    -1;
      goto _L1
_L7:
    JVM INSTR aastore ;
    JVM INSTR dup ;
    true;
    "j{\037~Cf";
    false;
      goto _L1
_L8:
    JVM INSTR aastore ;
    JVM INSTR dup ;
    2;
    "ik~";
    true;
      goto _L1
_L9:
    JVM INSTR aastore ;
    z;
_L1:
    JVM INSTR swap ;
    toCharArray();
    JVM INSTR dup ;
    JVM INSTR arraylength .length;
    JVM INSTR swap ;
    int i = 0;
    JVM INSTR swap ;
    JVM INSTR dup_x1 ;
    1;
    JVM INSTR icmpgt 130;
       goto _L2 _L3
_L2:
    JVM INSTR dup ;
    i;
_L5:
    JVM INSTR dup2 ;
    JVM INSTR caload ;
    byte byte0;
    switch(i % 5)
    {
    case 0: // '\0'
        byte0 = 8;
        break;

    case 1: // '\001'
        byte0 = 9;
        break;

    case 2: // '\002'
        byte0 = 106;
        break;

    case 3: // '\003'
        byte0 = 26;
        break;

    default:
        byte0 = 42;
        break;
    }
    byte0;
    JVM INSTR ixor ;
    (char);
    JVM INSTR castore ;
    i++;
    JVM INSTR swap ;
    JVM INSTR dup_x1 ;
    JVM INSTR ifne 130;
       goto _L4 _L3
_L4:
    JVM INSTR dup2 ;
    JVM INSTR swap ;
      goto _L5
_L3:
    JVM INSTR swap ;
    JVM INSTR dup_x1 ;
    i;
    JVM INSTR icmpgt 53;
       goto _L6 _L2
_L6:
    JVM INSTR new #104 <Class String>;
    JVM INSTR dup_x1 ;
    JVM INSTR swap ;
    String();
    intern();
    JVM INSTR swap ;
    JVM INSTR pop ;
    JVM INSTR swap ;
    JVM INSTR tableswitch 0 1: default 13
//                   0 22
//                   1 31;
       goto _L7 _L8 _L9
}
}
```

Comment: смотрел через notepad++, In Class Translator, DJ Java Decompiler 3.12, InJarTranslator-release.jar такие же крякозябры

Comment: почему бы не добавить в вопрос код, который получен декомпилятором?

Comment: @Stranger  
[Код](https://savetext.ru/PjK5CZPU)

Comment: @stranger-in-the-q [Код](https://savetext.ru/PjK5CZPU)

Comment: желательно код добавлять текстом, чтобы никто не бродил по вашим ссылкам, а потом этот код можно было бы использовать в ответе для вас :)

Comment: @andrew как добавить текст написано что не влезает

Comment: что и куда не влезает?

Comment: @andrew куда вбивать текст

Comment: нажимаете кнопку править под вопросом, и вставляете свой код, вместо слова `код` с ссылкой вставьте текстом код и отформатируйте его, если форматирование не получится, то сохраняйте правку как есть, и тогда тут его уже отредактируют другие пользователи

Comment: только не метки в java, пожалуйста

Comment: я могу дать недостающие классы или вообще скинуть весь jar файл

Comment: я путем нехитрых манипуляций понял что одно из переводимых слов означает dolphin подскажите кодировку хотябы